# Mac OSX Lion Apache server takes a while to start serving php scripts

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, osx-lion

I use the built in Apache (web sharing) and the built in PHP in OSX Lion to run DokuWiki as a personal information manager (nobody connects externally). From the previous version of OSX, there seems to be a chance in how web sharing works, and when I first try to open a page on localhost after not having used it for a while, it takes quite a while (upwards of 45 seconds) before the server responds. Subsequent pages are very quick. I wonder if this is some kind of "sleep function" where it suspends Apache when not in use, to save energy.

Is there a setting I can change to make it always respond right away?